# IntelliJ device selector for Flutter projects does not list Android emulators before they are started

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I use IntelliJ to develop Flutter apps. In the device selection dropdown in IntelliJ toolbar, the Android emulators that are not currently running do not appear. They do appear after I start them by other means (through Android Studio). So I cannot start up an Android emulator from IntelliJ. Why may this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set.

After setting it system-wide and restarting IntelliJ, the non-running emulators appear just fine. You can start them without leaving IntelliJ.

[image]

Comment: importantly, going `File > Invalidate > Restart` is not enough to restart IntelliJ in a way that updates the path environment variable. I had to close it, then open my project again, instead of making it restart itself.